# I can not find my mistake in AHU algorithm to detect if two trees are isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am using AHU algorithm to detect if two rooted trees are isomorphic or not, and I used this algorithm, I have sent it to my teacher and my teacher put a comment that there is a mistake in this algorithm according to your example of trees, but I can not see where is my mistake?

you see the small yellow box it the image? that's the comment

[image]

and this is the example according to the image, in this part, I am supposed to assign tuples in the form of parentheses to the leaves of trees and from  button to up to the root it gets children's parentheses

[image]

now I have to convert these parentheses to numbers, so I could obtain the canonical numbers of a tree... and then sort the number so for each tree I could have a unique number and compare these two numbers between then tree to check if they are similar or not

[image]

[image]

Here I have sorted the algorithm

[image]
and here is the algorithm for converting the parentheses to numbers, but the thing I do not see is from my perspective this algorithm matches with the examples I have provided, but as you see in the first image, the little yellow box is the comment I have gotten from teacher that "there is a mistake here", and I don't know what is it

What do you think is my mistake?

Comment: Well, you don't sort your strings in the first example. Also, in step 9, you don't specify what $t$ is, and try to assign something new to $L$ it seems? Step 9 should read *Give $v$ the tuple name "("L")"*

Comment: Another thing is that you use both capital and small letters for your variables. This is sloppy, and would generally give errors if you feed such things to a computer (or a rigorous mathematician)

Comment: @Vsotvep Thank you man, the thing is there is no sorting happening for the first algorithm, it is just the series of parentheses.. I can sort only after they are converted to the numbers which is second algorithm, but about the t, you are right, I found it online, how can I fix it ?

Comment: @Vsotvep so if I rewrite it like that, would it be ok? https://i.imgur.com/9Tqo360l.png

Comment: In that case, never mind the comment about sorting then. You have still forgotten the outer brackets, though :)

Comment: @Vsotvep outer brockets where bro?

Comment: Around your concatenation. "(())()" is not a tuple name, "((())())" is.

Comment: @Vsotvep Thank you for your help man but why I don't see any " (())()" anywhere?!

Comment: In Step 8: "Concatenate all the names for the children", you never put any outer brackets around them. If I would do this algorithm on the left tree in figure 9, I would get "()" for node D and B, then "()" for node C as well, since the concatenation of "()" is just "()", and then for node A, I would get "()()", as the concatenation of the names for B and C.

Comment: Also, I personally don't mind it as much, but I'm pretty certain there will be people on this site who don't like being called "man" and "bro". It also helps with getting taken seriously

Comment: @Vsotvep didn't know it, sorry... as you see I am quite new here, don't know the standard here and different from my culture. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Vsotvep And once again, Thank you, I got the point.